# A field extension of degree 8

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I would really appreciate it if you give me a hint on the following question:

If $K \subset F$ is a field extension of degree 8, then we must have $F=K(a,b,c)$ for some a, b and c in F.

Comment: out of my head, each extension element added in field carries its cojungate, so $3$ extensions carry $2^3=8$ total elements (including conjugates)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $a\in F\setminus K$, then $K(a)$ is of index at least two over $K$. If it is actually already F, just pick b,c at random. Otherwise,  Picking  $b\in F\setminus K(a)$ makes $K(a,b)$ of degree at least 4.

The last steps are exactly the same: can you carry it out without me spelling it out?

The easy generalization is that an extension of degree having n prime factors can be bridged with at most n adjunctions.

Comment: Thanks very much! It was pretty clear and precise!

Comment: So by the same way, we'll pick the third element in F\K(a,b) such that K(a,b,c) is of degree at least 8 over K, and at the same time this degree must divide [F:K]=8, so indeed the degree of K(a,b,c) over K is 8, which is equal to [F:K], and hence F=K(a,b,c).